# BC30456 'ITableSelection_SelectionChanged' is not a member of 'StandaloneTableClass'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vb.net

I am seeing this error BC30456 when building this DLL for VB.Net ArcMap extension. I see the following in the ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.xml which confuses me with the error.

```
<member name="M:ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTableClass.ITableSelection_SelectionChanged">
  <summary>Fires the layer update event. Required when SelectionSet changes.</summary>
```

---

Here is the progression

LodeNodes()

cAttachStandAloneTable

MyBase.ITableSelection_SelectionChanged()

```
Private Sub LoadNodes()
    Try
        lblStatus.Text = "Populating the tree view with the database layers"
        Me.Cursor = Windows.Forms.Cursors.AppStarting

        ' Get relAttachments table and set selection table for it
        Dim relAttach As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTable = New cAttachStandAloneTable(mFWS.OpenTable(modDBNaming.GetQualifiedTableName("relAttachments", mFWS)), "FCName")
        mRelAttachSel = relAttach

        ' Load relAttachments into dataset datatable
        PopulateRelAttachmentsTable(relAttach.Table)
        Dim relAttachDV As DataView = New DataView(mDataset.Tables("relAttachments"))
```

---

```
Public Class cAttachStandAloneTable
   Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.StandaloneTableClass

   Private _DisplayField As String
   Private _Name As String
   Private _Table As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable
   Private _Valid As Boolean
   Private _SelectionSet As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISelectionSet
```

---

```
Public Overloads Sub ITableSelection_SelectionChanged()
    MyBase.ITableSelection_SelectionChanged()
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you implementing this event interface? The help says that ITableSelection is implemented by StandaloneTable; are you instantiating to a new StandaloneTableClass() or an object that is a standalone table in your ArcMap? It's kind of hard to guess without some VB code, please edit your question to include the offending lines.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added the VB code to the original post. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: What are you trying to do with cAttachStandAloneTable? It seems a bit odd. You get a IStandaloneTable from IStandaloneTableCollection which is cast from ctype(ArcMap.Document,IMXdocument).FocusMap, once you find your standalone table then cast that wire the event from the preexistent standalone table.. this event only fires when the specific table that the event is wired from has a change in selection.